# Checking If the User clicked on Mail Link

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, anchor, mailto

I have a page with an email link

```
<a href="mailto:email@address.com?subject=Test Story&amp;body=abc.com
">Email Link</a>
```

I want to check that If User clicks on this link open the default Email client, but I also want to update in Database that User has mailed.
I know this is all happening at client side, Is there any way I can check either User clicked on it or not? onclick is not there for anchor tag.
Any help in this regard.

Comment: You can bind a click handler to the email anchors and fire an ajax request with details in the handler. Something on these lines http://jsfiddle.net/Q73y2/

Comment: Java or Flash can go that far only. What you've got there is an innocent anchor tag who hits that URL without any responsability of what happens outside the browser.

Comment: @PSL I have more than one such snippets in the page, even If I give them a class name that wouldn't serve the purpose

Comment: @AndrésTorres I agree , thats why I posted it here

Comment: @user1765876 Why not? you should be able to distinguish your own email tags from other anchor tags right. Also you can event set up specific data in data attributes as well specific to that email link and retrieve them on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen for the click event on `<a>` tags with a "mailto:" link. Assuming you're using jQuery, here is the code:

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').on('click', function(e){
  var email = $(this).attr('href').replace('mailto:', '');
  // submit action to server here.
});
```

Update: make sure this code is running after the DOM ready event, like so:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('a[href^="mailto:"]').on('click', function(e){
    var email = $(this).attr('href').replace('mailto:', '');
    // submit action to server here.
  });
});
```

Comment: It should do, here http://jsfiddle.net/YCby2/ Maybe you're using an older version of jQuery or your code is conflicting with it in some way? Can you check your console output or put your code online somewhere for me to see?

Comment: nothing is present on console, it only opens the email client, It works fine in jfiddle

Comment: Ok, have you inserted the code so that it runs after the DOM ready event? For example, inside this: `$(function($){ //code here });`

Comment: thanks for takiing out time for me, it is still not working, I am able to see the JS in source code but i think it is not triggered

Comment: I ran your updated code in console and it gave [
#document
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>​
<head>​…​</head>​
<body ">​…​</body>​
</html>​

Comment: No problem, can you give me a link to your code or put it on somewhere like jsfiddle?

Comment: Ok, but you have to understand it's hard to troubleshoot and understand the issue without seeing the code.

Comment: I agree,.. is there any other way to check if the code is being hit or not

Comment: If you could at least upload the "view source" of you page to here, then I can help you further. http://pastebin.com/

Comment: the code important for you is the last 5 to 6 lines..the code is in while loop that list this..

Comment: For a start it looks like you put the script inside a loop meaning the script will be executed multiple times which you don't wont. Unfortunately, it looks like you may have more issues than this and we're now getting outside of the scope of the original question. I'm sorry I couldn't be any more help to you.